# Prestashop SQL Manager Not Working As Expected

Tags: php, mysql, csv, prestashop-1.6

I am currently trying to export all product data to CSV in prestashop 1.6. Currently, the standard export to CSV function in Prestaop 1.6 does not deliver the Description and Short Description fields, so I am using SQL manager to do this. 
The problem is that when I create save my query, I do not have an option to export the results. When I click export, I am given a CSV file that contains the query, not the results. The screenshots below show the Prestashop Admin Screen where my query is saved, and the next screenshot shows the output of the CSV file after clicking export. What am I doing wrong?
[image: Saved query in Prestashop 1.6 SQL Manager]
[image: CSV result shows query, not result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem today and it has driven me mad for hours. Turns out that you must give write permissions to the folder "export" inside your admin folder because if you don't it defaults to the standard export csv without any error notice.

Comment: In my case, I removed all existing CSVs files in the export folder and it works. It's like there was a problem trying to replacing the file...